# Where can I browse common schemas?

Tags: xml, schema, dtd

It is hackish and myopic to write a new XML schema for a common data situation without considering existing standard schemas. It would be silly, for instance, to write a schema for recording internet bookmarks without considering [XBEL](http://pyxml.sourceforge.net/topics/xbel/).

Yet while a quick search yeilds hundreds of examples of how to write your own DTD, RNC, XSD, etc, I haven't seen a site where you can browse hundreds of standard schemas for particular problem spaces, e.g. product catalogs for e-commerce, office inventories, or lesson plans for teachers.

**Where can I browse often-used schemas?**

*EDIT: This question was originally about where to browse standard DTDs. Then it came to my attention that DTDs are dead - I've now changed my request from 'DTD' to 'schema', which I take to mean a "validatable specification for an XML-based markup language"*

*EDIT: Links like these, only more comprehensive: 
 1. [Wikipedia's list of Schemas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_schemas)
 2. [Altova's Schema Library](http://www.altova.com/resources_schemalib.html)
 3. [Liquid Technologies' XML Standards Library](http://schemas.liquid-technologies.com/)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Wikipedia's list of Schemas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_schemas)
2. [Altova's Schema Library](http://www.altova.com/resources_schemalib.html)
3. [Liquid Technologies' XML Standards Library](http://schemas.liquid-technologies.com/)*

Answer (score 2):

Is http://www.xml.com/pub/rg/DTD_Repositories > the sort of thing you're after?  I suspect existing standardization is less than you hope.

ALSO, I personally prefer RNC or at least XSD or another rich schema approach whenever possible, in preference to DTD.

Comment: Wow, what a shame - all the links on xml.com to DTD Repositories are ten years old and dead! OK, I give up, DTDs are dead.

Comment: Hang on.  There's still plenty of use of DTDs.  Give me a day, and I'll find repositories you can better use.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lot of GIS-related schemas:

http://schemas.opengis.net/